# Change attributes to a selected part of text in EditText

Tags: android, select, android-edittext

I've searched something around here but nothing came up.
I'd like to have an EditText in which I can change attributes like color or dimension of a selected part.

I've already tried with the spannable thing, from another question:

```
    TextView myTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
    String  textString = "StackOverFlow Rocks!!!";
    Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(textString);
    spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 14, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    myTV.setText(spanText);
```

I assume that I have to assign it to some onClick method..Also my problems are those two number, I should put some "selectedText" there instead I think.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to have an EditText in which I can change attributes like color or dimension of a selected part

If you want the *user* to "change attributes... of a selected part", [my recently-updated `RichEditText` offers that](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit). I do not have color or text size going yet, though, as those will need a toolbar (rather than my current action mode support).

> Also my problems are those two number, I should put some "selectedText" there instead I think

You are probably looking for [`getSelectionStart()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getSelectionStart%28%29) and [`getSelectionEnd()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getSelectionEnd%28%29).

Comment: @Lampione: You never touch the `.gradle/` folder yourself. Only edit the `build.gradle` in the project (or module) root directory.

Comment: @Lampione: Quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit#license): "The code in this project is licensed under the Apache Software License 2.0, per the terms of the included LICENSE file."